# Добавление записи в найденные файлы (eсho и find в одной команде)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня есть необходимость записывать строку "Done" во все файлы, которые более 1G

Знаю, что могу записать при помощи: `$ echo "Done" > text.txt`

И найти при помощи: `$ find /tmp/ -name '*.txt' -size +1G`

Но как объединить эти команды?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь опцией [`-exec`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=find&category=1&russian=2) для `find`:

```bash
find /tmp/ -name '*.txt' -size +1G -exec sh -c 'echo "Done" >> "{}"' \;
```

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендацию! Но у меня выводится следующая ошибка: `sh: echo "Done" >> /tmp/test_1.txt: No such file or directory`, хотя эти файлы точно есть (проверял этот путь через less)